Recipe terminated with fatal error: spawn pdflatex ENOENT. Source: LaTeX Workshop
I'm trying to use vscode for latex on Mac. I installed mactex and followed some steps like
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/TeX/texbin

so if I type which pdflatex on my .zsh, I can see return like
/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex

I also installed latex workshop and set configures in setting.json.
However I get this error message Recipe terminated with fatal error: spawn pdflatex ENOENT. Source: LaTeX Workshop. Anyone knows how to fix that?
I may need some detailed helps like to run what code in my .zsh.
followed some wrong solutions.

Check the file permissions of that pdflatex.
